# Issues with question mark in url

Tags: django, url, django-urls

Hi i am using multiple languages in my app and it is accessible by the url like `www.asd.com/reg/?lang=es`
Is there some way with which i can remove this **"?"** from my url and it becomes like `www.asd.com/reg/es`  and also my functionality of multiple language is working properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you access url with `?lang=es`, you will get a parameter named `lang` with value `es` in your view. This is generic HTTP url scheme.

With django, similar thing can be done using appropriate url pattern. For example:

```
url(r'^reg/(?P<lang>[\w]+)$', 'your_app.views.view_func',),
```

And in view

```
def view_func(request, lang=None):
    ...
    # lang will have value passed.
    # do your stuff
```

So when you access `www.asd.com/reg/es`, parameter `lang` will have value `es` in your view.

Comment: Ok , I am thinking that,but now you suggest that too so surely i'll try that. thanks

Comment: hi I face some issues in my view , because previously i have done it using middleware  , so there is nothing i have to write in my views.py , now if i used the same way in view it does not work or gives some errors.

Comment: @Inforian I don't get what is your problem and what have you tried.

Comment: I have tried this in my view I have put my code here  http://dpaste.com/hold/818076/

Comment: @Inforian I don't understand how that code suppose to work. You might be asking very simplified question than what you are trying to do.

Comment: IT is one of the code that i have tried..If you know the simple way then let me know

Comment: And one more thing when i used this url asd.com/reg/es it refer to the view  `def view_func(request, lang=None):`   or  `def view_func(request, lang):`  and when i try to print the value of lang it returns None

Answer (score 2):

Django 1.4 has a native support for such URLs - [`i18n_patterns`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#django.conf.urls.i18n.i18n_patterns). As I understand there was an app for this called [`django-i18nurls`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-i18nurls/) but it was included into django core

Also you can use [`django-localeurl`](http://packages.python.org/django-localeurl/) application for this ([available at BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-localeurl/)). It has a middleware that patches `request.path` and django's `reverse` function to achive locale URLs. Perhaps there are alternatives for this app

However this solutions will provide you URLs in format `www.asd.com/es/reg/`

Comment: I have to just installed it or there is anything that i have to edit in me app settings or other files

Comment: @Inforian if you have django 1.4 you only replace `patterns` with `i18n_patterns` in your root `urls.py` file - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#django.conf.urls.i18n.i18n_patterns If you want to use `django-localeurl` you need to install it and add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` and `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` - http://packages.python.org/django-localeurl/setup.html#setup Personally I prefer to use built-in functionality unless you need some extra-features from 3rd-party apps

Comment: Few days later i have tried it and follow the which are mentioned in the doc...but it doesn't work for me. BY the way if i installed it in my app and then what is the url to access it ???

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to add `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

Comment: Ok leave it can u tell me in general if i want to make my translation url specific not browser specific, how can i do that

Comment: @Inforian, sorry, but I don't understand what is "translation url specific not browser specific".

Comment: browser specific means as i changed the preference of lang in my browser , my app will collect the data from that lang local folder(let say es/django.po) and  display the data in that format.  AND url specific means it do not depends on the browser lang. but the lang. which i  specified  in the url it will automatically redirect to that lang locale folder

Comment: By default (https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py#L365-430) Django will search for language in this order: url path / session / cookies / HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE header (browser language). If you want to change this behaviour you need to inherit from `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` and write your custom `process_request` method. To activate language just call `django.utils.translation.activate(selected_lang)`. How to determine the `selected_lang` is up to you